# having troubles booting yumi multiboot on my windows 10 pc with a sandisk ultra usb 3.0 flash drive

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot, usb-flash-drive

I have been trying to multi-boot Linux distros on my MSI WS60 Windows 10 pc with a new 64gb Ultra 3.0 SanDisk flash drive. I have tried to troubleshoot the fast boot with Windows 10 and format the flash drive correctly, but I think that it must still have to do with one of those or some other problems. If anyone has done this recently with a updated Windows 10 pc and a SanDisk Ultra flash drive and has been successful throw me a line and some recommendations.

Comment: Found this article form PCworld today [link](http://www.pcworld.com/article/3057176/hardware/the-hidden-challenges-of-booting-from-a-usb-flash-drive.html). Had some use full information. I might have to try to play with the BIOS Setup.

Comment: I tried legacy booting but it gave me a boot error when I restarted computer and had usb option chosen. Not sure where my problem starts and ends at the moment.